# Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for MyComponent: (?,?,?) in ng test

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner

I am using Angular 6, with Angular CLI AOT to compile. So far so good until I was going to do some UI tests, in addition to current tests for functions, running with Karma.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({

    templateUrl: 'notFound.component.html'
})
export class NotFoundComponent implements OnInit {


    constructor(private router: Router) {
        console.debug('NotFoundComponent created');
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    home() {
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }

}
```

The application is running fine and the component can be rendered by NG runtime properly. However, when running with ng test, I get:

```
Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for NotFoundComponent: (?)
```

And I have to do this to make things work in test:

```
constructor( @Inject(Router) private router: Router)
```

Do I miss something? Is it possible to make ng test to accept injection of Router without @Inject() in the constructor?